# How do you respond to "Where are you from"?

Tags: greetings

I am from spain and I am learning English. Someone said "where are you from". I said, "Spain".
Should I have said something else?

Comment: A one-word answer is a bit abrupt; you could say "I come from Spain", or even mention the city or region.

Comment: ^ Or, "I'm from Spain".

Comment: A one word answer is only abrupt if it seems to end the conversation. It would be fine to say, "Spain. How about you?" or perhaps, "Spain. Have you ever been there?" or maybe, "Spain. But I've been looking forward to seeing America/England/Australia for a long time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question like "Where are you from?" is what is called "[small talk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/small-talk)". The point of small talk is rarely about simply exchanging information. It is about carrying on a conversation between people who do not know each other well. A simple one word response, while not necessarily inappropriate, does not fulfill this implied purpose. Responses like the other answer may be perceived as less abrupt or rude, but they also do not fulfill this purpose.

To me, a more appropriate response would be:

- I am from Spain, how about you?
- I come from Spain, where are you from?

or if you prefer short responses:

- Spain, you?

This response is equally as abrupt as yours, but would be unlikely to be perceived as rude.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking few words can sometimes be perceived as rude by listeners. But you're trying to learn a foreign language, so it's fine for you. In general, I suggest trying to speak in full sentences or clauses, varying the words and grammatical constructions as you best you can. This way, you gain more practice, improving your English, and impressing your listeners.

As for greetings, here are some templates to work with:

- I come from Spain.
- I come from a Spanish town/city/county/province called ....
- My hometown is ..., which is in Spain.
- I was born and raised in the town/city of ..., in Spain.